# Is it possible to scale the plot for better visualisation?

Tags: matlab, scaling, subplot

MATLAB: I want to make the plots (at least the drag) more visual, maybe my scaling the plot in some way. Are there any ways to make the plot look better than my code does (unable to add an attach an image). I want it to be clear the drag forces oscillate approx twice for every oscillation of lift. The red dotted line is just to show that the drag oscillates about 0. The lift1 and drag1 are both 10001x1 double, and dt1 is 1x10001 double. My goal is to have the drag above the lift in the same plot, to illustrate the oscillations. I could also adjust the whitespace (split the plot in two if possible) to make it more smooth. Right now the lift oscillates between -0.8 and 0.8, and drag between 4.9 and 4.4, and therefore not very visible.

````
close all
clc

lift1 = dlmread('liftforce.txt');
drag1 = dlmread('dragforce.txt');

dt1=linspace(0, 10, length(lift1));

lift=lift1(100:end,:);
drag=drag1(100:end,:);
dt=dt1(:,100:end);

figure()
plot(dt,lift,dt,drag)
xlabel('Time')
ylabel('liftforce, dragforce')
legend('liftforce','dragforce')
line([0 10],[0 0],'Color','red','LineStyle','--')```
````

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Superimposing two plots with different axes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33651674/superimposing-two-plots-with-different-axes)

Comment: What does your current figure look like?